# `google-chrome` and `chromium-browser` were not found. Try setting the CHROMOTE_CHROME environment variable or adding one of

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu

I have a docker image with RStudio installed.

My flexdashboard app has a section to download a flextable

```
  save_path = str_c(image_dir, "IX_overviewp2_", sub('-','_',current_quarter), ".png")
  save_as_image(ft,
                path = save_path,
                zoom = 3 ,
                webshot = "webshot2") # save flextable as png
```

but when I get to the section of the code, I receive the error:  `"google-chrome" and "chromium-browser" were not found. Try setting the CHROMOTE_CHROME environment variable or adding one of these executables to your PATH. Error in initialize(...) : Invalid path to Chrome`

I updated my docker image to include chrome with the last two `RUN` commands of my dockerfile, but this still does not solve my issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
FROM rocker/verse

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.8 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

ADD . ./home/rstudio

ADD requirements.txt .
ADD install_packages.r .

# Miniconda and dependencies
RUN cd /tmp/ && \
        wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda3 && \
        /root/miniconda3/condabin/conda install -y python=3.7
ENV PATH=$PATH:/root/miniconda3/bin

#RUN npm install phantomjs-prebuilt --phantomjs_cdnurl=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads

# installing python libraries
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# installing r libraries
RUN Rscript install_packages.r

RUN if ! [[ "16.04 18.04 20.04 21.04 21.10" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]]; \
then \
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported."; \
    exit; \
fi

RUN sudo su
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN exit
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/rstudio

# Install Chrome WebDriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install Google Chrome
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in you dockerfile:

```
RUN wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_5.5.2805.35-1_amd64.deb 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ./vivaldi-stable_5.5.2805.35-1_amd64.deb && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo CHROMOTE_CHROME=/usr/bin/vivaldi >> .Renviron
```